# Disable accessibility (VoiceOver) on a MKMapView

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

What I want to do is to disable accessibility on a `MKMapView`.
Actually `VoiceOver` reads all the element on the map: roads, POI ecc. ecc.

So I tried this

```
[map setIsAccessibilityElement:NO]
```

but don't work...how to achieve this? I am missing something?

Comment: Why are you so anxious to make your app not accessible?

Comment: because maps informations are not relevant to the blind, for the app purpose

Comment: There is so much ignorance in your statement, i don't even know where to start.  There are disabilities outside of blindness and accessibility tools outside of VoiceOver, for which the accuracy of that information is still relied upon by the OS.

Answer (score 3):

Your 'MKMapView' may be seen as a container whose elements should not be seen by VoiceOver thanks to the [`accessibilityElementsHidden'](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#hide-elements) property.

```
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    map.accessibilityElementsHidden = true
}
```

Using this property as shown in the code snippet above **disables VoiceOver on a MKMapView**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed, you are missing something.  This isn't how the "isAccessibilityElemnt" property works.  By setting your view as not an accessibility element, you're only telling VoiceOver to ignore THAT view, not that view and all of its children.

What you want to do, is write a recursive function to set the "isAccessibilityElement" property to no for all subviews.  I got caught in VA in the epic snowstorm, without my mac.  I just started playing around with Swift, but don't have a complier, so this is Swift (ish) pseudo code.

```
func setA11yElementRecursive(view: UIView, toThis: bool) {
    view.isAccessibilityElement = toThis

    for (View v : view.subviews) {
        setA11yElementRecursive(v, toThis)
    }
}
```

DISCLAIMER: The implications of this however, are that every element you set as not an accessibility element, VoiceOver (and any other AT) will assume that your view is not important for accessibility.  Meaning it will be completely ignored!  Anyone using VoiceOver on your app (or at least on this view) will assume that nothing is there.  Your app will appear as a blank canvas.  Partially sighted users who rely on VoiceOver to read the small print on your labels will swipe over elements on your UI and it will appear to them as no element is there.  They will be confused as to why they see a label there, but can't have it read out to them.  There are very few circumstances in which setting this property to NO on items that present information is appropriate.  Even if you believe that blind people shouldn't be using your app or this particular feature of your app.

Comment: Thanks to the answer and the disclaimer, you don't know but the reason of my question is that I want  to improve the user experience of blind people who use VoiceOver. My View have at the bottom a button that do a critical task, so I want that the user wich use VoiceOver can do quickly that action.

Comment: Alternate methods of performing actions does not mean that you should block otherwise available information.  I have been doing accessibility analysis of native ios applications for 5 years, I have never recommended that a client set informative views as not important for accessibility.  Let alone an entire hierarchy of views.  This really only makes sense in one circumstance, to hide views behind a modal dialogue.

Comment: @AP Consider using `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` to highlight the button if you feel it's appropriate. But remember that VoiceOver users don't navigate only by swiping left and right; they can drag their finger around the screen to have the contents under their finger read aloud. It would be a confusing experience for maps *not* to work the way they typically do.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I disable voice-over functionality only for my app. @ChrisCM